# Laravel with jQuery autocomplete generating 500 error

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting a 500 error trying to implement this code https://gist.github.com/imranismail/10200241 and can't see what I am doing wrong.

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="entity-name">Entity Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control entity-name" name="entity-name" id="entity-name" placeholder="Entity Name">
</div>
```

...

```
$( ".entity-name" ).autocomplete({
    source: "index",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('.entity-name').val(ui.item.value);
    entity}
});
```

Route

```
Route::get('index', 'PagesController@autocomplete');
```

Controller

```
public function autocomplete(){
    $term = Input::get('term');

    $results = array();

    $queries = DB::table('entity_records')
        ->where('entity_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')
        ->take(5)->get();

    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = [ 'id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->entity_name ];
    }
    return Response::json($results);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting in your log files?

Comment: [2015-07-17 23:29:26] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found' in /Users/neil/Sites/testsite/app/Http/Controllers/PagesController.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add at the top od your controller:

```
use Input;
```

Comment: This will tell PHP to look for this class in global namespace instead od your controller's namespace

Comment: You are right. After your suggestion of looking at the log I added use Input; and found I needed to add use Response, and use App\Http\Controllers\DB; as well and now it works.